# difference between simple query string and multi match query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Hi I am using two search query which is giving similar result. what is difference between these two query simple query string and multi match?

1- simple_query_string

```
   {
     "size": 50,
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "should": [
           {
             "simple_query_string": {
               "query": "text search",
               "fields": [
                 "Field1^2",
                 "Field2^4",
                 "Field3^6",
                 "Field4^8",
                 "Field5^10", 
                 "Field6^12",
                 "Field7^14", 
                 "Field8^16",              
                 "*^.1"
               ]
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     },
      "sort": [
       "_score",
       {
         "Field6.keyword": {
           "order": "desc"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
```

2- Multimatch query

```
    GET index/_search
    {
      "size": 50,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "text search",
                "fields": [
                  "Field1^2",
                  "Field2^4",
                  "Field3^6",
                  "Field4^8",
                  "Field5^10", 
                  "Field6^12",
                  "Field7^14", 
                  "Field8^16",              
                  "*^.1"
                ],
                "type": "most_fields"
              }
            }
          ]
```

Both query gives same result in same order. Is there any advantage of any query ?

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are the same as they will be converted to same `query string`. If you use `query string` your query will be slightly faster as you Elastic doesn't need to `rewrite` your query.

> All queries in Lucene undergo a "rewriting" process. A query (and its sub-queries) may be rewritten one or more times, and the process continues until the query stops changing. This process allows Lucene to perform optimizations, such as removing redundant clauses, replacing one query for a more efficient execution path, etc. For example a Boolean → Boolean → TermQuery can be rewritten to a TermQuery, because all the Booleans are unnecessary in this case. The rewriting process is complex and difficult to display, since queries can change drastically. Rather than showing the intermediate results, the total rewrite time is simply displayed as a value (in nanoseconds). This value is cumulative and contains the total time for all queries being rewritten.

You can check your query performance and rewrite time by setting `"profile": "true"` in your query, for more information check official documentation of Elastic search [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html).